# cassandra - udt column, data insertion problem

Tags: cassandra

I had created a UDT as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE killrvideo.video_encoding (
  bit_rates set<text>,
  encoding text,
  height int,
  width int
);
```

created table as follows:

```
create table test(
  name text primary key, 
  mydata frozen<video_encoding>
);
```

trying to insert data:

```
insert into test(name, mydata) 
values(
'srini',"{ {'data', 'ssssecond'}, 'tttttest', 23, 444}"
);
```

Getting error as:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:98 no viable alternative at input ')' 
(...name, mydata) values('srini',["{ {'data', 'ssssecond'}, 'tttttest', 23, 444]}")...)
```

Please assist me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [correct syntax for it](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertUDT.html): `{udt_field_name1: value1, udt_field_name2: value2}`, and don't put the content into the double quotes:

```
insert into test(name, mydata) values('srini', 
{ bit_rates: {'data', 'ssssecond'}, encoding: 'tttttest', height: 23, width: 444});
```